# how to add javascripts to jekyll?

Tags: javascript, jekyll

So, I am trying out jekyll and I have successfully added my .scss files and they are working but there seems to be a problem with the .js files.

I have tried adding .coffee files and adding the plug-in jekyll-coffeescript but that too isnt working

so my folder structure is this:

```
\javascripts
  |__ main.js
\_includes
\_sass
\_layouts
\_config.yml
\index.html
```

now in the main.js file i just have

```
console.log("this worked");
alert("hello");
```

and I have a head.html in the _includes folder where I added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{site.baseurl}}/javascripts/main.js" ></script>
```

when I load the page nothing is happening, why? what is the mistake?

I added the same thing like this and it worked

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
console.log("this worked");
alert("hello");
</script>
```

so why is the previous method not working

I have written nothing in the _config.yml file about any javascript

Comment: can you check where exactly your scripts are getting added into the generated assests.

Comment: so in \_site\javascripts\main.js as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have kept your **main.js** file under `your_site/assets/js/javascripts/`

Try this path to load the js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/javascripts/main.js" ></script>
```

Also you can check `localhost:port/assets` to see other files as well.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: yes so i opened the view-source thing and clicked on the link to see if its pointing to the file and it is              *Edit: changed ad to and*